# HLS inequality not suitable to bound this integral

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality, bounds-of-integration

I am trying to bound the following integral for $f \in L^{n/2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$:
$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) \lvert x-y \lvert^{2(2-n)}f(y)dxdy$. Because of the factor 2 in the exponent, the condition $0<\lambda<n$ in the Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality fails for $\lambda=2n-4$ and $n>3$. Is there another way to bound this integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm probably missing something, but how about this: Suppose $0<f$ is continuous (don't even worry about integrability for now). Fix $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $r>0$ be such that $f(y)>f(x)/2>0 $ for every $y\in B:=B_\delta(x)$. Then use polar coordinates to write
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |x-y|^{-\alpha} f(y)\, dy & \geq \dfrac{f(x)}{2}\int_B |x-y|^{-\alpha}\, dy\\
& = \dfrac{f(x)}{2} \int_{B_\delta(0)} |y|^{-\alpha}\, dy.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
So if $\alpha>n$ (as is the case for you if $n>3$), then the first integral is $\infty$ for any $x$, so the whole integral is infinite in this case.

Comment: Well, there must be a problem because the HLS do provide a finite bound for $n$ up to 3 (with different conditions of integrability for $f$, but as you said, that's not the point here), and if I understand correctly what you are saying, it's supposed to fail for at least any positive $\alpha$ right?

Comment: @Spida: I corrected a typo, it should be $\alpha>n$ instead. But the point is that $\lambda= 2n-4>n$ for any $n>3$, so the expression is infinite in these cases.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much for you help!